# File Hiding in Android

Tags: android

I have created a file explorer using list view that lets us view all memory card folders and files.Now I when i click on any file a Dialog Box appears that gives three option/button that is hide,uncover and cancel. Now I am having trouble in retrieving file name from list view and changing its name so that file get hidden in gallery.I am uploading my code and it is giving error Could not execute method from activity.

Java File Containing Logic For Hiding.
**onHide()** and **onUnhide()** are methods for hiding and unHiding files

```
package com.example.settingspro;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class pichide extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;

    private TextView myPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pichide);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.hidelistlayout, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead())
            {
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }
            else
            {
                Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
                settingsDialog.setTitle("Options");
                settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout1, null));
                settingsDialog.show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
            settingsDialog.setTitle("Options");
            settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout1, null));
            settingsDialog.show();
        }
    }
    public void onHide(View v)
    {
        long id;
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);

        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead())
            {
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }
            else
            {
                String s = file.getName();
                File f = new File(s);
                File f1 = new File(s + ".aaa");
                f.renameTo(f1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "File Hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String s = file.getName();
            File f = new File(s);
            File f1 = new File(s + ".aaa");
            f.renameTo(f1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "File Hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onUnhide(View v)
    {
        long id;
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead())
            {
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }
            else
            {
                String s = file.getName();
                File f = new File(s);
                File f1 = new File(s);
                f.renameTo(f1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "File UnHidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String s = file.getName();
            File f = new File(s);
            File f1 = new File(s);
            f.renameTo(f1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "File UnHidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onBack(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

LayoutFile of Dialog Box Button_layout1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hidebt"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onHide"
    android:text="@string/hide"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/unhidebt"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hidebt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hidebt"
    android:onClick="onUnhide"
    android:text="@string/unhide"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backbt"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/unhidebt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/unhidebt"
    android:onClick="onBack"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

pichide.xml in which listview is used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/status_bar_background22"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/nodata"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My ListView Item Layout hidelistlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Log:

```
08-29 19:14:18.572: D/AndroidRuntime(11136): Shutting down VM
08-29 19:14:18.572: W/dalvikvm(11136): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    ... 11 more
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.example.settingspro.pichide.onHide(pichide.java:124)
08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    ... 14 more
08-29 19:14:18.632: W/ActivityManager(315):   Force finishing activity com.example.settingspro/.pichide
08-29 19:14:18.642: W/WindowManager(315): Failure taking screenshot for (123x221) to layer 21020
```

Comment: Can you show some error lines from your log.

Comment: Added The log cat to the post

Comment: Read your exceptions. You have a `IndexOutOfBounds` because you try to access element `-1`.

Comment: Thanks will see the error and tell if any other error occurs :)

Answer (score 0):

You should always read more lines of stacktrace than first ones. Here your culprit:

```
 08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
 08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
 08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):   at com.example.settingspro.pichide.onHide(pichide.java:124)
 08-29 19:14:18.602: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):   ... 14 more
```

so look at line **124** of `pichide.java` (btw: you use wrong naming convention) and fix :)

Comment: I am getting error in this line what might be wrong    File file = new File(path.get(position));